# $sort doesn't work in aggregate pipeline mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregate

I am stuck on this problem and I have absolutely no idea of why this doesn't work.

I have a huge collection 'Course' about 12millions of documents and I want to do and aggregate pipeline on it. This is my code :

```
const records = await Course.aggregate([
{
  $match: { swimmer: ObjectId('5fa750d9c4a9ca53c5347dc6') },
},
{
  $sort: { time: 1 },
},
{
  $group: {
    _id: {
      season: '$season',
      bassin: '$bassin',
      type: '$type',
      disance: '$distance',
    },
    course: { $first: '$$ROOT' },
  },
},
```

]).allowDiskUse(true);

To this pipeline works just find if I take off the sort stage but it's impossible to get any respond with it... The code is pending until it throws me this error:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoNetworkTimeoutError: connection 11 to XXX.XXX.XX.XX:XXXX timed out

I match the data before sorting to avoid a huge sort, there are only about 200 documents to sort and there is an index on time

I really don't understand why this aggregate can't send me the result...

there is my schema :

```
   const courseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  type: {
    bassin: {
      type: String,
      enums: ['25M', '50M'],
      required: [true, 'Une course doit avoir une taille de bassin'],
    },
    nage: {
      type: String,
      enums: ['NAGE_LIBRE', 'BRASSE', 'DOS', 'PAPILLON', 'QUATRE_NAGES'],
      required: [true, 'Une course doit avoir un type de nage'],
    },
    distance: {
      type: String,
      enums: ['50M', '100M', '200M', '400M', '800M', '1500M'],
      required: [true, 'Une course doit avoir une distance'],
    },
  },
  time: { type: Number, required: [true, 'Une course doit avoir un temps'] },
  tempsPassages: {
    type: Map,
    of: Number,
  },date: { type: Date, required: [true, 'Une course doit avoir une date'] },
  season: {
    type: Number,
    min: [2000, 'La saison ne peut être inférieur à 2000'],
    max: [
      new Date().getFullYear() + 1,
      `La saison ne peut être supérieur à ${new Date().getFullYear() + 1}`,
    ],
    required: [true, 'Une course doit avoir une saison'],
  },
  place: { type: String, lowercase: true, trim: true },
  niveauCompetition: {
    type: String,
    enums: ['DEP', 'REG', 'NAT', 'ZON', 'INT'],
    // required: [true, 'Une course doit avoir un niveau de compétition'],
  },
  swimmer: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Swimmer',
    required: [true, 'Une course doit avoir un nageur'],
  },
  club: {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, 'Un club doit avoir un nom'],
      trim: true,
      // unique: [true, 'Nom de club déjà existant'],
    },
    _id: {
      type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Club',
      required: [true, 'Un club doit avoir un identifiant FFN'],
    },
    departement: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, 'Un club doit avoir un département'],
      trim: true,
      enum: enums.EDepartement,
    },
    region: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, 'Un club doit avoir un région'],
      trim: true,
      enum: enums.ERegion,
    },
    country: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      enum: ['FRANCE'],
      default: 'FRANCE',
    },
  },
  notes: {
    country: Number,
    region: Number,
    departement: Number,
    club: Number,
  },
  swimmerAge: {
    type: Number,
    required: [true, "L'age du nageur doit etre fourni"],
  },
  swimmerCategory: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'La catégory du nageur doit etre fournie'],
    enums: ['AVENIRS', 'JEUNES', 'JUNIORS', 'SENIORS'],
  },
  swimmerSex: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Le sexe du nageur doit etre fournie'],
    enums: ['F', 'M'],
  },
});
```

And there is an exemple of a document course in the database
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cmgz4.png)

I tried to sort by swimmerAge instead of time everything works just find but by season same problem...

Thank you for helping me !

Comment: Can you post your schema please?

Comment: Yes of course, there is my schema :

Comment: I just posted it

Comment: What are you trying to do with `$project`? Can you explain the purpose of your query?

Comment: I want to get a list of an array of the highest performances by season, bassin = pool, type = type of the race and distance is the distance of the race. for that I match by the swimmer first to get all the races done by this swimmer then I need to sort them by time and finally group by season, bassin, type and distance and keep the first race (the highest)

Comment: I found out that if I sort by season I got the same issue but if I sort by swimmerAge everything work just find

Comment: I deleted the index on time an now thank god it's working !! but I still don't understand why the index ruined everything..

Comment: Run explain with and without sort to figure that ou.